# Generate One year dates using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar

I have a table with three ID and Dates
i want generate dates of one year from current date and before and after six months
Then i want to plot three dates on this one year generated calandar
I tried

```
SELECT (TO_DATE(SYSDATE)-180) + ROWNUM DT
  FROM (SELECT 1
          FROM DUAL
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <=180)
```

Comment: `SYSDATE` is already of datatype `DATE`, if you call `TO_DATE`, it expects a string, converts the date to a varchar2 and back to a date.

Comment: You probably want to use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` to cut of the time part of `SYSDATE`.

Comment: Can you please show expected output?

Comment: The date generator line might be better as `connect by trunc(sysdate) + rownum < add_months(sysdate,6)`, instead of using `level` and a number. I don't understand what data you have or what you mean by plotting though.

Comment: I want to highlight 3 dates on calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "month" is variable, so you may want to double check if "6 months" is really what you're looking for. It can give unexpected results if you don't know the oddities of date math.

That being said, a calendar which contains 6 months on either side of the current date can be generated with the following. Note that 184 days is the longest a 6 month span can last (July-December).

```
SELECT dt
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - 184) + LEVEL AS dt
          FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 369)
 WHERE dt BETWEEN add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -6) AND add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally following what you said: there's a table with 3 IDs and their dates, and you want to *plot* the calendar.

Using a hierarchical query, dates are generated as

```
SQL> with
  2  threeid (id, datum) as
  3    (select 1, date '2020-05-29' from dual union all
  4     select 2, date '2020-01-01' from dual union all
  5     select 3, date '2020-02-29' from dual
  6    ),
  7  cal as
  8    (select add_months(datum, -6) + column_value - 1 datum
  9      from threeid cross join
 10       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                           connect by level <= add_months(datum, 6) - add_months(datum, -6)
 12                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13      where id = 1         --> for the 1st ID; change that for other calendars
 14    )
 15  select * from cal order by datum;

DATUM
----------
29.11.2019
30.11.2019
01.12.2019
02.12.2019
03.12.2019
<snip>
25.11.2020
26.11.2020
27.11.2020
28.11.2020

366 rows selected.
```

If you want to *plot* that, instead of line #15 you'd use *this* ...

```
 <snip>
 15  select lpad(month, 20, ' ') month,
 16    "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"
 17  from (select to_char(dt, 'fmMonthfm YYYY') month,
 18          week,
 19          max(decode(to_char(dt, 'd'), '1', lpad(to_char(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Mon",
 20          max(decode(to_char(dt, 'd'), '2', lpad(to_char(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Tue",
 21          max(decode(to_char(dt, 'd'), '3', lpad(to_char(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Wed",
 22          max(decode(to_char(dt, 'd'), '4', lpad(to_char(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Thu",
 23          max(decode(to_char(dt, 'd'), '5', lpad(to_char(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Fri",
 24          max(decode(to_char(dt, 'd'), '6', lpad(to_char(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Sat",
 25          max(decode(to_char(dt, 'd'), '7', lpad(to_char(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Sun"
 26        from ( select dt,
 27                      case when     dt >= to_date(to_char(dt, 'dd/') ||'12/'||
 28                                          to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy')
 29                                and wk = '01'
 30                           then '53'
 31                           else wk
 32                      end week
 33               from (select datum dt, to_char(datum, 'iw') wk
 34                     from cal
 35                    )
 36             )
 37        group by to_char(dt, 'fmMonthfm YYYY'), week
 38       )
 39  order by to_date( month, 'Month YYYY' ), to_number(week);
```

... and get *that*:

```
MONTH                Mon      Tue      Wed      Thu      Fri      Sat      Sun
-------------------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
       November 2019                                     29       30
       December 2019 30       31
       December 2019                                                        1
       December 2019  2        3        4        5        6        7        8
       December 2019  9       10       11       12       13       14       15
       December 2019 16       17       18       19       20       21       22
       December 2019 23       24       25       26       27       28       29
        January 2020                    1        2        3        4        5
        January 2020  6        7        8        9       10       11       12
        January 2020 13       14       15       16       17       18       19
        January 2020 20       21       22       23       24       25       26
        January 2020 27       28       29       30       31
       February 2020                                               1        2
       February 2020  3        4        5        6        7        8        9
       February 2020 10       11       12       13       14       15       16
       February 2020 17       18       19       20       21       22       23
       February 2020 24       25       26       27       28       29
          March 2020                                                        1
          March 2020  2        3        4        5        6        7        8
          March 2020  9       10       11       12       13       14       15
          March 2020 16       17       18       19       20       21       22
          March 2020 23       24       25       26       27       28       29
          March 2020 30       31
          April 2020                    1        2        3        4        5
          April 2020  6        7        8        9       10       11       12
          April 2020 13       14       15       16       17       18       19
          April 2020 20       21       22       23       24       25       26
          April 2020 27       28       29       30
            May 2020                                      1        2        3
            May 2020  4        5        6        7        8        9       10
            May 2020 11       12       13       14       15       16       17
            May 2020 18       19       20       21       22       23       24
            May 2020 25       26       27       28       29       30       31
           June 2020  1        2        3        4        5        6        7
           June 2020  8        9       10       11       12       13       14
           June 2020 15       16       17       18       19       20       21
           June 2020 22       23       24       25       26       27       28
           June 2020 29       30
           July 2020                    1        2        3        4        5
           July 2020  6        7        8        9       10       11       12
           July 2020 13       14       15       16       17       18       19
           July 2020 20       21       22       23       24       25       26
           July 2020 27       28       29       30       31
         August 2020                                               1        2
         August 2020  3        4        5        6        7        8        9
         August 2020 10       11       12       13       14       15       16
         August 2020 17       18       19       20       21       22       23
         August 2020 24       25       26       27       28       29       30
         August 2020 31
      September 2020           1        2        3        4        5        6
      September 2020  7        8        9       10       11       12       13
      September 2020 14       15       16       17       18       19       20
      September 2020 21       22       23       24       25       26       27
      September 2020 28       29       30
        October 2020                             1        2        3        4
        October 2020  5        6        7        8        9       10       11
        October 2020 12       13       14       15       16       17       18
        October 2020 19       20       21       22       23       24       25
        October 2020 26       27       28       29       30       31
       November 2020                                                        1
       November 2020  2        3        4        5        6        7        8
       November 2020  9       10       11       12       13       14       15
       November 2020 16       17       18       19       20       21       22
       November 2020 23       24       25       26       27       28

64 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

(That *nice* calendar query is originally (at least, I think so) posted on [OraFAQ](https://www.orafaq.com/node/2029) site; I adjusted it, hoping that it correctly displays dates)